# How to troubleshoot issue with port supposedly open?

Tags: debian, networking, iptables

I had succsessfully opened a port on my debian machine using iptables:
[image]

I started a webserver that I have written in go and that listens to connection on port 12345. It worked fine until this morning. Now the connections expire with timeout and I don't know hot to find the root cause. Here's lsof output (I now changed to 12333 just to give it a try):

[image]

netstat -tlpan and uname:

[image]

netstat after configuring webserver to listen to tcpv4:
[image]

code in go:

[image]

iptables:

[image]

Comment: Please post the output of `netstat -tlpan`, run as root while the problem exists. Also, please detail the OS and say what the `getenforce` command says (if it exists).

Comment: According to the `netstat` output, your webserver does not listen on TCPv4 but only on TCPv6, and there it listens on port 12333, not 12345. Change the code or config to adjust.

Comment: yes, i had changed to 12333 just to try. I will see how to configure go to listen to tcpv4

Comment: now it binds to port 12345 using tcp v4 but no luck yet

Comment: What do you mean, you cannot connect?  Please write the go code line containing `listen("tcp", ???)`.

Comment: Please white the output of `iptables -L -nv` (as root) during the problem. Please note that `iptables` rules do not persist and are reset the next time the machine boots.

Comment: yes, I run iptables at every boot

Comment: You are saying that you cannot connect. That could be a problem on the source machine (some firewalls filter outgoing connections to anything but {53,80,443,8080}). However: PLEASE TRY `iptables ... ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED` - RELATED was probably missing.

Comment: Please post text as text (not as an image). It is easier to read that way (especially by blind people).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I know, I'm working on remote with vnc and copy paste does not work, never understood how to enable

Comment: @Ned64 do I have to add "RELATED" to both input and output?

Comment: @gianpaolo You do not need 12345 in the output at all. I adjusted by Answer below. Please try.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, TCP/UDP confused, please use the new version below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily you would have iptables rules like this:

```
# define standard chains and default behaviour (here ACCEPT, could be DROP)
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# everything as a continuation is OK, This will be the bulk => 1st rule
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# drop garbage packages
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# server services including your new web server
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12345 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2103 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

# (perhaps some more, do include SSH!)

# allow incoming ping (good for testing)
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT

# rest / default: DROP!
-A INPUT -j DROP

# Again, everything related is allowed
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# allow DNS, both UDP and TCP
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

# allow access to time servers (NTP)
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow anything else you need, e.g. for OS update servers
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing ping
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# disallow the rest!
-A OUTPUT -j DROP

# Forward usually not needed except for routing and NAT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

You were missing the RELATED state.

The rules like above are usually written to the file

```
# /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

They can be saved by the command

```
# iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

and restored from that file by

```
# iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

There is a system service called `iptables.service` which restores the tables from that file upon boot.  Depending on your system you may or may not have that service, and it may be disabled (`systemctl status iptables`).

If you do have that service (`yum install iptables-services` in CentOS) then, after testing your iptables rules, save them once,

```
# iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

then activate the service

```
# systemctl enable iptables
# systemctl start iptables
```

After the next boot, test whether this works by checking the current entries by issuing (as root, like all commands here):

```
# iptables -L -nv
```

Comment: how do I add these rules? so far I have used a script:                           iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 12345 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

Comment: could I break something with iptables? it's ok if I had to reconfigure at every reboot, so in case i made a mess I can do a reboot, otherwise they would kill me

Comment: @gianpaolo During test, leave out the DROP lines - or enter them after logging in by SSH. The existing connection should be "RELATED,ESTABLISHED".

Comment: ok, do I have to add "iptables" at each line and save in a .sh command to be executed?

Comment: @gianpaolo Just added details on that. It's easier (and more common) with that file.